# ios - when opening a push notification while the app is active, it cases a crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, urbanairship.com

I am testing push notifications. I have this scenario:

When I am on a random screen, and I get a push notification and open that notification, the system tries to take me to the screen which the push notification forces.  And that causes what seems to be a segue error:

```
Mar 31 11:08:52 ancient-phone Marketing[14788] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LoginController openBusinessTopic]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c5b3ae0'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x318412a3 0x394db97f 0x31844e07 0x31843531 0x3179af68 0x40ae3 0x337f290d 0x337f1f6b 0x33649d59 0x336496cd 0x3364911b 0x3534a5a3 0x3534a1d3 0x31816173 0x31816117 0x31814f99 0x31787ebd 0x31787d49 0x353492eb 0x3369d301 0x404ff 0x39912b20)
```

How can I prevent this? And what is the reason that this happens? And is there a way to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your error says that `LoginController` is being sent a `openBusinessTopic` message, and that this class does not implement that method.  You can either implement `openBusinessTopic` in your `LoginController` class, or try to figure out if there is a different object that should have been sent that message.

Comment: thank you, the reason that happened is because I happened  to have randomly last been on the LoginController screen. So there would be no natural segue for openBusinessTopic from it.

Comment: What my code tried to do is go from AppDelegate, and call the ViewController and that controller had that segue

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code that does that.  Can you add it to your question?